# GRUB menu while installing xubuntu 15.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, live-usb, 15.04

I have windows 7 installed on my system and I'm trying to dual boot my system using a live usb stick of xubuntu 15.04(64 bit) which I created using unetbootin software.
my issue is when I boot from the usb it shows
"BOOTING IN INSECURE MODE"
and then grub 2 screen appears and im unable to reach the screen which has options like "install" and "try xubuntu without installing"
I searched google and found out that "insecure boot" error happens in system having uefi/efi .I'm not able to reach the installation screen
Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of readings on the web i realized that the software i used [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) does not create uefi compatible bootable usb and then i tried [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) to make a uefi compatible bootable usb and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use Windows 7 to create a bootavle DVD. Download Ubuntu ISO, double click the file to create DVD. Restart and boot from DVD.

Comment: How would this fix the uefi issues?

Comment: i dont think that would solve my issue, is there any other solution